# Bash loop on files in folder without specific pattern

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have to cycle over the files present in a folder but I dont want to cycle over files with a specific pattern ("Reverse"). Here is the code

Thanks

```
DIRECTORY=/Users/Qi.Wang/projects/CH12F3/data/CH12F3.LAM-HTGTS_mMYC.220512
outputDir=/Users/Qi.Wang/projects/CH12F3/
pw=$(pwd)
cat blank.txt > ./config.txt
c="$pw/config.txt"
o=0
for i in $DIRECTORY/*.fna; do
    ((o=o+1))
    s=${i##*/}
    b=${s%.fna}
    b="${o}_$(echo $b | awk '{ gsub(/_PairEnd+/, " " ); print $1 }')"
    outputDirs="$outputDir$b"
    printf "%s\t" $b >> ./config.txt
    printf "%s\t" $s >> ./config.txt
    cat end.txt >> ./config.txt
    printf "perl /Users/andy/projects/HTGTS/pipeline/align_tools/TLPpipeline.pl %s %s which=%s assembly=mm9 blatopt=mask=lower outdir=/%s -skipred -skipredadd -skipblu -skipbluadd \n" $c $DIRECTORY $o  $outputDirs >> ./command.sh
done
```

I Also have another minor problem. When i printf outdirs=%s the variable that is printed is $outputDir that starts with a "/" but after it got printed by printf, looks like the / is not there anymore.

Comment: What's the question? In bash you can use extended globbing to match names that don't include a pattern.

Comment: I don't see `outdirs=%s` in the `printf`. There's `outdir=/%s`, is that what you're talking about? I don't see any way that the `/` at the beginning could be removed. You should get `//` because there's `/` in the printf and `/` at the beginning of the variable.

Comment: Remember to quote all your variables in case they contain special characters.

Comment: And your `awk` command does put spaces in `$b`, which goes into `$outputDirs`, so you definitely need to quote `$outputDirs` in the `printf` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `awk` command puts spaces `$b`, so `$outputDirs` will contain spaces. Therefore, you need to quote it to make it a single argument to `printf`. You should also quote all the other variable arguments.

Also, since you're creating a `perl` command line, you'll want `outdir=%s` to be a single argument, so you should put single quotes around that as well.

```
printf "perl /Users/andy/projects/HTGTS/pipeline/align_tools/TLPpipeline.pl '%s' '%s' 'which=%s' assembly=mm9 blatopt=mask=lower 'outdir=/%s' -skipred -skipredadd -skipblu -skipbluadd \n" "$c" "$DIRECTORY" "$o"  "$outputDirs" >> ./command.sh
```

To skip files with `Reverse` in the name, enable extended globbing and use a non-matching pattern.

```
shopt -s extglob

for i in "$DIRECTORY"/!(*Reverse*).fna; do
```

Comment: Great! Now the "/" problem is solved!! I just need to solve the for loop with the globbing that i dont really understand how to exclude files with specific pattern, i mean i have to loop over all the files that has .fna extension excluding the files that has "reverse" in the name

Comment: The obvious way is with an `if` statement that checks if the name contains `reverse`.